# How to install Rails 4 (final) along with the latest version of Ruby via RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've found ways to install Rails 4 via RVM but all of them refers to the beta version.

How to install the final version along with the latest version of Ruby (via RVM)?

Answer (score 24):

`rvm get stable` to get the last rvm versión

`rvm install 2.0.0` to install ruby 2.0

`rvm use 2.0.0` to use ruby 2.0

`gem install rails` to install rails 4.0

Comment: No, but if you rvm is system wide then you should belongs to rvm group

Answer (score 5):

First you need to update your rvm to the latest stable version

```
rvm get stable
```

Then, you can check all available ruby versions by

```
rvm list known
```

It should display something like this[image]

then install ruby 2.0 by

```
rvm install 2.0.0-p247
```

once it's done, install rails by

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

Comment: In which system you are? I am on Ubuntu.. Still showing me `[ruby-]2.0.0-rc1
[ruby-]2.0.0-rc2
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p0]
ruby-head` Not any of the patch of ruby2.0.0

Comment: I run those commands on mountain lion. But I just run them on my vps, which is running ubuntu 12.04 and get the same result.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 13.04 although